# Content overlapping when display size is too small

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an issue with my site; I cannot find a way to make my content stop overlapping when the actual display size is smaller than the original display size - `1920x1080`.
I would like to know how I could either scale down the whole page or just make my content not overlap.

Thanks in advance for any help provided!

```js
var i = 0;
var txt1 ="foqjpcqkcqèckqècqq."
var txt2 ="iqj0pqcjqp'cjqpjciq'pcjqi'cjqic."     
var txt3 ="jqopjfgoqpkfpqovmqpvqvkqpoèvkqp"   
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;

var speed = 100; /* The speed/duration of the effect in milliseconds */

window.onload = function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt2.length) {

    document.getElementById("about_l1").innerHTML += txt1.charAt(i);
    document.getElementById("about_l2").innerHTML += txt2.charAt(i);
    document.getElementById("about_l4").innerHTML += txt3.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
  if (i == 0){

  }
}

const scrollToTop =() => {
  const c = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
  if (c > 0) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollToTop);
    window.scrollTo(0, c - c / 8);
  }
};
scrollToTop();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:500');
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-y: visible;
  margin:0px;
}
.back{
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("../media/backgif2.gif");
  background-size: cover;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  color: white;
}
.thx{
  position: fixed;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  bottom: 15px;
}
hr.style-one {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  width: 110%:;
  background: #333;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ccc, #333, #ccc);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ccc, #333, #ccc);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #ccc, #333, #ccc);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #ccc, #333, #ccc);
}
.visuallyhidden{
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fade-in-right ease 0.8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
.visuallyhidden2{
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fade-in-right ease 0.8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
}
.visuallyhidden3{
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fade-in-right ease 2s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
.Lvisuallyhidden{
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fade-in-left ease 0.8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
.Lvisuallyhidden2{
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fade-in-left ease 0.8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
}
.Lvisuallyhidden3{
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fade-in-left ease 2s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
nav{
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top:50px;
  text-align:center;
}
nav a{
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight:500;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#16151b;
  margin:0 15px;
  font-size:16px;
  letter-spacing:1px;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
nav a:before{
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background:#16151b;
  top:47%;
  animation:out 0.2s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0.58, 0.97) 1 both;
}
nav a:hover:before{
  animation:in 0.2s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0.58, 0.97) 1 both;
}
iframe{
  height: 250px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
}
input:focus {outline:0;}

p{
  width: 45%;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif; font-size:21px;letter-spacing:1px; font-weight:500;text-transform:uppercase;text-align: left;
  color:#16151b;
  position: absolute;
}
@keyframes in{
  0%{
    width: 0;
    left:0;
    right:auto;
  }
  100%{
    left:0;
    right:auto;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes out{
  0%{
    width:100%;
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
  }
  100%{
    width: 0;
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes show{
  0%{
    opacity:0;
    transform:translateY(-10px);
  }
  100%{
    opacity:1;
    transform:translateY(0);
  }
}
@keyframes fade-in-right {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-25px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
@keyframes fade-in-left {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(25px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
#div1{
  height: 1200px;
}
#div2{
  height: 500px;
}
#div3{
  height: 500px;
}
#about_p{
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  height: 5%;
  width: 70%;
  left: 15%;
  top: 30%;
}
#about_p2{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 95%;
}
#bar1{
  position: absolute;
  width: 45%;
  max-width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  top: 39%;
  left :28%;
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
}
#bar2{
  position: relative;
  height: 135px;
  top: 715px;
  left :9%;
  border-left: 4px solid black;
} 
#vid1{
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  top: 95%;
}
#vid2{
  position: absolute;
  left: 55%;
  top: 150%;
}
#vid3{
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  top: 205%;
}
#title1{
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif; font-size:50px;letter-spacing:1px; font-weight:500;text-transform:uppercase;text-align: left;
  left: 5%;
  bottom: -10%;
}
#title2{
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif; font-size:50px;letter-spacing:1px; font-weight:500;text-transform:uppercase;text-align: left;
  left: 80%;
  bottom: -70%;
}
#title3{
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif; font-size:50px;letter-spacing:1px; font-weight:500;text-transform:uppercase;text-align: left;
  left: 5%;
  bottom: -120%;
}
#arrow{
  position: absolute;
  height: 10%;
  left: 90%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TEST</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/inspiration.css" />
    <script src="javascript/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="javascript/inspiration.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="back"></div>
    <header>
    <nav id="navbar">
        <a href="about.html">About</a>
        <a href="works.html">Works</a>
        <a href="inspiration.html">Inspiration</a>
        <a href="price.html">Price</a>
        <a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a>
    </nav>
    </header>
    
    <div id="bar1" class="visuallyhidden2"></div>
    
    <div id="div1">
      <p id="about_p" class="Lvisuallyhidden3">
        <span id="about_l1">Music inspires people and I've been in</span>
        <span id="about_l2"><br>If those artists can inspire you too then may</span>
      </p>
    </div>
 
    <div id="div2">
      <label id="title1" class="Lvisuallyhidden2">A$AP Rocky</label>
      <iframe id="vid1" class="Lvisuallyhidden"   
      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
      </iframe>

      <p id="about_p2" class="visuallyhidden2">
        <span id="about_l3"><br>fdcjqiojqoicmqiojcopipcjqpèèpq qpoi jcqip jqè qè kq èjq èpjq q jqè jqpj pq c</span>
        <span id="about_l4"><br>fdcjqiojqoicmqiojcopipcjqpèèpq qpoi jcqip jqè qè kq èjq èpjq q jqè jqpj pq c </span>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="div3">
      <label id="title2" class="visuallyhidden2">kzmzmzmzmzmz</label>
      <iframe id="vid2" class="visuallyhidden"
      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
      </iframe>
    </div>

    <div id="div4">
      <label id="title3" class="visuallyhidden2">Kendrick Lamar</label>
      <iframe id="vid3" class="visuallyhidden"
      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
      </iframe>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <input id="arrow" type="image" src="media/arrow.png" onclick="scrollToTop()" />
    </footer>
    </div>
    
<a class="thx" style="background-color:black;color:white;text-decoration:none;padding:4px 6px;font-family:-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, &quot;San Francisco&quot;, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Ubuntu, Roboto, Noto, &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, Arial, sans-serif;left: 51%;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;line-height:1.2;display:inline-block;border-radius:3px;" href="https://www.instagram.com/manu.fma/?hl=fr" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" title="Magnolia's instagram"><span style="display:inline-block;padding:2px 3px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="height:12px;width:auto;position:relative;vertical-align:middle;top:-1px;fill:white;" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><title></title><path d="M20.8 18.1c0 2.7-2.2 4.8-4.8 4.8s-4.8-2.1-4.8-4.8c0-2.7 2.2-4.8 4.8-4.8 2.7.1 4.8 2.2 4.8 4.8zm11.2-7.4v14.9c0 2.3-1.9 4.3-4.3 4.3h-23.4c-2.4 0-4.3-1.9-4.3-4.3v-15c0-2.3 1.9-4.3 4.3-4.3h3.7l.8-2.3c.4-1.1 1.7-2 2.9-2h8.6c1.2 0 2.5.9 2.9 2l.8 2.4h3.7c2.4 0 4.3 1.9 4.3 4.3zm-8.6 7.5c0-4.1-3.3-7.5-7.5-7.5-4.1 0-7.5 3.4-7.5 7.5s3.3 7.5 7.5 7.5c4.2-.1 7.5-3.4 7.5-7.5z"></path></svg></span><span style="display:inline-block;padding:2px 3px;">Magnolia
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e6w5aLp7/

Comment: Be careful to your css selectors. Exemple you used `.wrapper` with class selector but in your html you use an id `<div id="wrapper"></div>` so you css is not applied.

Comment: >Make sure that the parent element is of  `position:absolute` is `relative`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `position: absolute` everywhere you should consider to use other approach like :

- CSS flex (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
- CSS grid (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

It's more flexible and responsive.

You also can use other units like viewports units (`vw` or `vh`) to use screen size relative units : https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/

Comment: Thank you **vw** and **vh** units seem to be very useful  i'm going to try that

Comment: I tried using grid but i wasn't able to make it work :/

Answer (score 1):

`absolute` position will cause elements to overlap. Better to use `position:relative` and `display:block` to stack elements on the page. Please refer to: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Consider using bootstrap, responsive framework out of the box. Get started by pasting css and js link and you are ready to go:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: `display:block` will take up the full width of the parent

Comment: you can save time using bootstrap that i have linked above. it has a very good responsive grid system for all devices. see the link above in the answer